# How to open .tmpl file same as html file in GoLand or PyCharm IDE?

Tags: html, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, go-templates, goland

I'm using GoLand IDE. When I open an HTML file I could see different colors in the file content, but when I open a `.tmpl` file which is used in `Go-Template` file, I couldn't check it like an HTML file, but when I change its postfix to `.html` instead of `.tmpl` it occurs.

So, how can I open `.tmpl` (`Go-Template`) file same as an HTML file in GoLand IDE?

Also, I tried with PyCharm IDE but the result was the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add `*.tmpl` to the list of patterns registered for **HTML** file type in **Settings | Editor | File Types**

Comment: And what about VSCODE?

Answer (score 2):

in VSCODE :

Go to the `Settings`->`textEditor`->`files`->`add items`

then define *.tmpl as a key and html as value

`*.tmpl : html`

Comment: the question post here doesn't ask about VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.gohtml` extension instead of `.tmpl` in the Goland IDE.